# Communications between components

Tags: wpf, silverlight, prism

Is there are any other alternative mechanism for communications between loosely coupled components in the application such as EventAggregator in Prism?

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343980/event-aggregator-implementation-sample-best-practices

Comment: Are you just interested in alternatives or do you a problem to solve? If you want to solve the problem, please describe it also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [message bus](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Message-oriented_middleware) .

Comment: Just follow the link and read the article. There are named several products.